# How to train a model with only an Embedding layer in Keras and no labels

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, word-embedding

I have some text without any labels. Just a bunch of text files. And I want to train an Embedding layer to map the words to embedding vectors. Most of the examples I've seen so far are like this:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, Flatten, Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, embedding_dim, input_length=maxlen))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    metrics=['acc'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
    epochs=10,
    batch_size=32,
    validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

They all assume that the Embedding layer is part of a bigger model which tries to predict a label. But in my case, I have no label. I'm not trying to classify anything. I just want to train the mapping from words (more precisely integers) to embedding vectors. But the `fit` method of the model, asks for `x_train` and `y_train` (as the example given above).

How can I train a model only with an Embedding layer and no labels?

**[UPDATE]**

Based on the answer I've got from @Daniel Möller, Embedding layer in Keras is implementing a supervised algorithm and thus cannot be trained without labels. Initially, I was thinking that it is a variation of Word2Vec and thus does not need labels to be trained. Apparently, that's not the case. Personally, I ended up using the [FastText](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText) which has nothing to do with Keras or Python.

Comment: Well, in that case you simply want a model with only an embedding layer https://medium.com/@satnalikamayank12/on-learning-embeddings-for-categorical-data-using-keras-165ff2773fc9

Comment: @desertnaut Thanks for the link. It's definitely an interesting article. But as far as I can see, they are still dealing with a classification problem with labels provided. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think it's a different case.

Comment: I was trying for the same thing, to create embeddings from a corpus. Couldn't find anything with Keras. But I found this blog in which they used Tensorflow to create embeddings from a huge corpus. [word embeddings using tensorflow](https://github.com/priya-dwivedi/Deep-Learning/blob/master/word2vec_skipgram/Skip-Grams-Solution.ipynb)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does it make sense to do that without a label/target?

How will your model decide which values in the vectors are good for anything if there is no objective?

All embeddings are "trained" for a purpose. If there is no purpose, there is no target, if there is no target, there is no training.

If you really want to transform words in vectors without any purpose/target, you've got two options:

- Make one-hot encoded vectors. You may use the Keras `to_categorical` function for that.
- Use a pretrained embedding. There are some available, such as glove, embeddings from Google, etc. (All of they were trained at some point for some purpose).

---

#### A very naive approach based on our chat, considering word distance

Warning: I don't really know anything about Word2Vec, but I'll try to show how to add the rules for your embedding using some naive kind of word distance and how to use dummy "labels" just to satisfy Keras' way of training.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, Subtract, Lambda
import keras.backend as K
from keras.models import Model

input1 = Input((1,)) #word1
input2 = Input((1,)) #word2

embeddingLayer = Embedding(...params...)

word1 = embeddingLayer(input1)
word2 = embeddingLayer(input2)

#naive distance rule, subtract, expect zero difference
word_distance = Subtract()([word1,word2])

#reduce all dimensions to a single dimension
word_distance = Lambda(lambda x: K.mean(x, axis=-1))(word_distance)

model = Model([input1,input2], word_distance)
```

Now that our model outputs directly a word distance, our labels will be "zero", they're not really labels for a supervised training, but they're the expected result of the model, something necessary for Keras to work.

We can have as loss function the `mae` (mean absolute error) or `mse` (mean squared error), for instance.

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

And training with word2 being the word after word1:

```
xTrain = entireText
xTrain1 = entireText[:-1]
xTrain2 = entireText[1:]
yTrain = np.zeros((len(xTrain1),))

model.fit([xTrain1,xTrain2], yTrain, .... more params.... )
```

Although this may be completely wrong regarding what Word2Vec really does, it shows the main points that are:

- Embedding layers don't have special properties, they're just trainable lookup tables
- Rules for creating an embedding should be defined by the model and expected outputs
- A Keras model will need "targets", even if those targets are not "labels" but a mathematical trick for an expected result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I believe the underlying algorithm of an Embedding layer is something similar to Word2Vec (or maybe GloVe). And if that's the case, learning a Word2Vec does not need the data to have a label. There are other implementations of Word2Vec (in other programming languages) and they are all like that. Also, I've studied the algorithm as well. Word2Vec relies on the proximity of the words in the text and it does not have a use for the label. In all the examples that use Embedding layer, the labels are for the other layers, not for the Embedding one.

Comment: Please take a look at this article. It points out that my request is valid but it does not provide a solution: https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-word-embedding-layers-deep-learning-keras/

Comment: You're talking about "pretrained" embeddings. Labels are for the embedding "as well", unless the embedding is pretrained and you explicitly tell the model that you don't want it to be trainable.

Comment: The fact that you can use a pretrained Embedding layer shows that training an Embedding layer does not rely on the labels. Just think about it. If Embedding layers are trained based on some specific problem, you won't be able to use them in a different problem. The only reason why pretrained mappings work is that they only depend on the corpus and not any specific problem. Please trust me on this. Word2Vec only relies on the proximity of the words in a text and there's no label involved. Perhaps that's why Embedding has to be the very first layer in Kersa. It's not actually a part of training.

Comment: Trust me about Keras. Embedding layers are trained for a specific purpose. And this sentence is false: "The fact that you can use a pretrained Embedding layer shows that training an Embedding layer does not rely on the labels." - It shows that a pretrained embedding that can be used in many problems was trained in a problem that is very general.

Comment: And, supposing an embedding is not part of training, why would you want to train it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183832/discussion-between-mehran-and-daniel-moller).